# Calculate the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{5h}$

Tags: analysis

The function $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$.Calculate the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{5h}$.That's what I have tried:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{5h}&=\frac{2}{5}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+h)}{2h}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{f(x_{0}-h)}{-h}\\&=\frac{2}{5}(f'(x_{0})+\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f({x_{0}})}{h})+\frac{1}{5}(f'(x_{0})+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_{0})}{h})\\&=\frac{3}{5}(f'(x_{0})+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_{0})}{h})\end{align}$$
Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: You are aware that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0)}{h}$ does not exist unless $f(x_0)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better rewrite
$$\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0-h)}{5h} =\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{5h}=\frac25\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)}{2h}+\frac15\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{-h}$$

Comment: So,if we take the lim,is it equal to $\frac25lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)}{2h}+\frac15lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{-h}$=$\frac{2}{5}f'(x_{0})+\frac{1}{5}f'(x_{0})=\frac{3}{5}f'(x_{0})$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{5h}=\frac 1 5\left[2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0})}{2h}+\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0}-h)-f(x_{0})}{-h}\right]$$